# Computing distance of a vector from the center of K-means cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have training data set and I ran K-means on it with K=4 and got four cluster centers. For new data point(s), I would like to know not only the predicted cluster but also the distance from that cluster's center. Is there an API to compute the euclidean distance from the center ? I can make 2 API calls, if that is needed. I am using Scala and I couldn't find any example anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me ...

```
def EuclideanDistance(x: Array[Double], y: Array[Double]) = {
  scala.math.sqrt((xs zip ys).map { case (x,y) => scala.math.pow(y - x, 2.0) }.sum)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Spark 2.0 [Vectors.sqdist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors$@sqdist(v1:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector,v2:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector):Double) can be used to calculate the squared distance between two Vectors.

You could use a UDF to calculate for every point the distance from its center, like so:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vectors, Vector}
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

// Sample points
val points = Seq(Vectors.dense(1,0), Vectors.dense(2,-3), Vectors.dense(0.5, -1), Vectors.dense(1.5, -1.5))    
val df = points.map(Tuple1.apply).toDF("features")

// K-means
val kmeans = new KMeans()
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setK(2)
val kmeansModel = kmeans.fit(df)

val predictedDF = kmeansModel.transform(df)
// predictedDF.schema = (features: Vector, prediction: Int)

// Cluster Centers
kmeansModel.clusterCenters foreach println
/*
[1.75,-2.25]
[0.75,-0.5]
*/

// UDF that calculates for each point distance from each cluster center
val distFromCenter = udf((features: Vector, c: Int) => Vectors.sqdist(features, kmeansModel.clusterCenters(c)))

val distancesDF = predictedDF.withColumn("distanceFromCenter", distFromCenter($"features", $"prediction"))
distancesDF.show(false)
/*
+----------+----------+------------------+
|features  |prediction|distanceFromCenter|
+----------+----------+------------------+
|[1.0,0.0] |1         |0.3125            |
|[2.0,-3.0]|0         |0.625             |
|[0.5,-1.0]|1         |0.3125            |
|[1.5,-1.5]|0         |0.625             |
+----------+----------+------------------+
*/
```

NOTE: `Vectors.sqdist` calculates squared distance between 2 Vectors (without square root). If you need Euclidean distance necessarily, you could use `Math.sqrt(Vectors.sqdist(...))`